# Visual Studio 2013 and Microsoft CRM/XRM Development - Project Type unsupported

Tags: c#, crm, visual-studio-2013, xrm

Has anyone been developing XRM on VS2013?

I've attempted to open my project and recieve the following message on the CRM plugins/Workflows/CRM package projects in the solution:

'Needs migration'
or
'Incompatible'

Normally this means that you need to install a plugin for VS2013 to support the project types. I've installed the CRM 2013 SDK addins and it hasn't resolved the problem.

The project type GUIDs are 4C25E9B5-9FA6-436c-8E19-B395D2A65FAF and 88A30576-7583-4F75-8136-5EFD2C14ADFF.

Cheers,
Jon

Comment: You can search for those GUIDs and find out what is missing. 4C25E9B5-9FA6-436c-8E19-B395D2A65FAF indicated the CRM plugin. I would try re-install the SDK and plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately I can't find an SDK that supports VS2013 for those GUIDs. CRM2011 supports vs2010 and CRM2013 supports VS2012.